# Why Primary phase is skipped in the election?

Tags: discussion, election

Usually in the other community elections, there are three phases involved.

- Nomination
- Primary
- Election

But here, [primary phase](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/2?tab=primary) was skipped. Yesterday the [nomination phase](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/2?tab=nomination) was closed and today the [election phase](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/2?tab=election) is directly opened.

When I'm trying to vote for any candidate in the primary phase, I'm receiving the warning

> Voting is locked for this candidate.

What is the reason the primary phase is skipped in the election?

Comment: If you and one other candidate had thrown your hat into the ring, we would have had a primary :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function of the primary phase (as in US politics and probably elsewhere) is to *narrow down the field* to a manageable set of candidates for final election. Since the field had only 9 candidates, that wasn't necessary; the SE software passes up to 10 candidates to the last phase anyway:

> After 7 days, the top 30 nominees, ordered by reputation, advance to the primary phase. However, if there are 10 or fewer candidates, we skip directly to the election phase.

The primary's secondary function is to give more time to campaign with the questionnaire and so forth, but (at present) that's just a side effect, not a deliberately-supported function, and [SE does not yet have any provision for that effect if there are fewer than 11 nominees](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277665/improve-election-schedule-with-respect-to-the-questionnaire).